# What is the best facebook connect library for node.js?

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js

I've seen multiple tools for working with node.js and facebook connect.  However many of them seem incomplete, overly-complex (non abstract) or no longer updated/maintained.

I've found these three projects:

https://github.com/DracoBlue/node-facebook-client

https://github.com/dominiek/node-facebook

https://github.com/egorFiNE/facebook-connect

https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth

Here one of the authors even discusses why he once again rolled his own, due to shortcomings in other implementations:

http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/bb46cb08e51fdda6

Does anyone have any real experience actually authenticating users and storing their facebook id's in their database using node.js and facebook connect?

I have a feeling that the answer is pretty much no and I'll have to build on top of one of the above systems to make things much simpler, but I wanted to check first.

Edit: Note make sure you use the STABLE version of node.js

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you not find ciaranj's [connect-auth](https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth)

```
const fbId = ""; #x
const fbSecret = ""; #y
const fbCallbackAddress= "http://localhost:4000/auth/facebook";
//var RedisStore = require('connect-redis');
var express= require('express');
var auth= require('connect-auth')
var app = express.createServer();
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.cookieDecoder());
  app.use(express.logger());
  //app.use(connect.session({ store: new RedisStore({ maxAge: 10080000 }) }));
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(auth( [
    auth.Facebook({appId : fbId, appSecret: fbSecret, scope: "email", callback: fbCallbackAddress})
  ]) );
});


app.get('/logout', function(req, res, params) {
    req.logout();
    res.writeHead(303, { 'Location': "/" });
    res.end('');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, params) {
    if( !req.isAuthenticated() ) {
        res.send('<html>                                              \n\
          <head>                                             \n\
            <title>connect Auth -- Not Authenticated</title> \n\
            <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/en_US/core.js"></script> \n\
          </head><body>                                             \n\
            <div id="wrapper">                               \n\
              <h1>Not authenticated</h1>                     \n\
              <div class="fb_button" id="fb-login" style="float:left; background-position: left -188px">          \n\
                <a href="/auth/facebook" class="fb_button_medium">        \n\
                  <span id="fb_login_text" class="fb_button_text"> \n\
                    Connect with Facebook                    \n\
                  </span>                                    \n\
                </a>                                         \n\
              </div></body></html>');
    } else {
         res.send( JSON.stringify( req.getAuthDetails()) );
    }
});

// Method to handle a sign-in with a specified method type, and a url to go back to ...
app.get('/auth/facebook', function(req,res) {
  req.authenticate(['facebook'], function(error, authenticated) { 
     if(authenticated ) {
        res.send("<html><h1>Hello Facebook user:" + JSON.stringify( req.getAuthDetails() ) + ".</h1></html>")
      }
      else {
        res.send("<html><h1>Facebook authentication failed :( </h1></html>")
      }
   });
});
```

app.listen(4000);

[image: facebook settings]

Comment: It seems to work a lot of the way but down just hangs on facebooks redirect to /auth/facebook ... and does nothing

Comment: it works like a charm for me! You have to set const fbCallbackAddress= "http://localhost:4000/auth/facebook"; offcourse change localhost:4000/ part

Comment: changed snippet a little bit. You have to offcourse specify auth middleware variables.

Comment: awesome Alred thanks for your help ... turns out now it always gets rejected ... aka authenticated is always false after it goes through the process but everything else works

Comment: Alfred could i maybe chat with you directly?

Comment: Turns out anyone that finds this heres whats going on: It works fine in node v 0.2.6 but if you move up to the 0.3.7 branch it goes into an infinite loop.  Check out the convo here: https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth/issues#issue/31

Comment: Hm.. In my case, req.isAuthenticated() and req.authenticate() is not working. I saw this error message, "500 TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'authenticate'". I'm using express 2.3.10. What should I do to use those functions?

Comment: The last time I checked(with node v0.2.6 ;)) it was a long time ago. I would now recommend to use everyauth. I have uploaded gist at https://gist.github.com/1039402. The dependencies are already in node_modules folder, but you need to configure FacebookId,FacebookSecret,FacebookSiteURL.

Answer (score 8):

I find [passport-facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook) fairly simple and useful.
I also like that the core passport module has 80+ auth strategies.
(e.g. twitter, google, foursquare, github, digg, dropbox).

From the creator's github README:

```
// Set up the strategy
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
            return done(err, user);
        });
    }
));

// Use the authentication
app.get('/auth/facebook',
    passport.authenticate('facebook'),
    function(req, res){
        // The request will be redirected to Facebook for authentication, so
        // this function will not be called.
});

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
        res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: I used this library as well. Works well for authenticating through Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Brian Noguchi's everyauth. It works w/ node.js v.0.4.x. You can find that [here](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth).

It has native support for mongodb using [mongoose-auth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth) plugin, again written by brian.