# Scaling Node.js

Tags: node.js, scalability

I'm fairly new to large-scale server-side development. I want to write a server using Node.js, but before I forge ahead I'd like to know what the general principles are for scaling node up to, say, 20 queries per second.

The service I'm writing will largely be an interface to a database, plus authentication and validation of input data.

Comment: What do you mean by "scaling node up"? Starting multiple node processes?

Comment: 20 queries per second is fairly low. Node.js should be able to handle thousands of simultaneous connections. Just don't do heavy loop processing because it will block the whole interpreter. Your use case should be fairly light weight in comparison. In Node, database connections are automatically spawned to threads and handled asynchronously at the javascript level.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

### Load balancing

Most probably for the most simple sites you don't need any scaling at all. Just one single box will get you covered. After that you should do load balancing like you are mentioning which is almost the same for every architecture(like you are saying you could start multiple node processes first. But when you get really big you need more boxes).

[Nginx load balancing example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/loadbalanceexample/):

```
http {
  upstream myproject {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 weight=3;
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    server 127.0.0.1:8002;    
    server 127.0.0.1:8003;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://myproject;
    }
  }
}
```

### Redis

> 20 queries per second

No sweat for node.js. You should use redis as your datastore because it is insane fast :). There is even a c library for node when you use [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis).

```
npm install hiredis redis
```

Hiredis is what gives you kickass performance because it compiles to C code inside node. Here are some benchmarks from redis when used with hiredis.

```
PING: 20000 ops 46189.38 ops/sec 1/4/1.082
SET: 20000 ops 41237.11 ops/sec 0/6/1.210
GET: 20000 ops 39682.54 ops/sec 1/7/1.257
INCR: 20000 ops 40080.16 ops/sec 0/8/1.242
LPUSH: 20000 ops 41152.26 ops/sec 0/3/1.212
LRANGE (10 elements): 20000 ops 36563.07 ops/sec 1/8/1.363
LRANGE (100 elements): 20000 ops 21834.06 ops/sec 0/9/2.287
```

When you look at those numbers then 20/s is **NOTHING** :).

### Authentication

---

**Update:**

- [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth)
- [openid](https://github.com/havard/node-openid)

---

I am telling this a lot but for the love of god please don't try to implement your own authentication-system. It is probably going to be unsafe(a lot can go wrong), a lot of work. For authentication you should use facebook-connect, twitter single sign-in, etc using the excellent [connect-auth](https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth) library. Then you are covered safe because they have experts testing there login-systems for holes and the also don't transmit passwords via plain-text but thank for god use https. I also have answered a topic for a user who wanted to use [facebook-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484825/what-is-the-best-facebook-connect-library-for-node-js/4485300#4485300).

### validation of input data

To validate input you could use [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator).

```
var check = require('validator').check,
    sanitize = require('validator').sanitize

//Validate
check('test@email.com').len(6, 64).isEmail();       //Methods are chainable
check('abc').isInt();                               //Throws 'Invalid integer'
check('abc', 'Please enter a number').isInt();      //Throws 'Please enter a number'
check('abcdefghijklmnopzrtsuvqxyz').is(/^[a-z]+$/);

//Sanitize / Filter
var int = sanitize('0123').toInt();                  //123
var bool = sanitize('true').toBoolean();             //true
var str = sanitize(' \s\t\r hello \n').trim();      //'hello'
var str = sanitize('aaaaaaaaab').ltrim('a');        //'b'
var str = sanitize(large_input_str).xss();
var str = sanitize('&lt;a&gt;').entityDecode();     //'<a>'
```

There also is this [forms](https://github.com/caolan/forms) library to help you create forms.

Comment: @nornagon your welcome :). Especially remember not to write your own login-system ;). Also Jeff Atwood(Stackoverflow author) strongly advises against it! => http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/openid-one-year-later/

Comment: Yep, I was never planning to.

Comment: You can use HAProxy for load balancing WebSockets as nginx won't work :) This is provided you are developing applications that require you to use WebSockets somewhere! Just an addition to @alfred's already awesome answer.

Comment: @Shripad K thanks, will keep that in mind if we ever need websockets!

Comment: An example HAProxy setup, in case you use websockets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360221/haproxy-websocket-disconnection/4737648#4737648

Comment: Good answer.  I'd strongly recommend passport.js over everyauth though.

Comment: what about passport instead of everyauth?

Comment: would nginx balacing take care of the fact that if an even is emited by a client it will emit it to all connected clients to the different ws servers?