# Using Nodejs for writing a web application

Tags: node.js, scalability

I am considering developing a web site which has many characteristics of a social networking site. The website, I am considering will have a lot of apps, which will interact with the database, and also, scraping other websites for information and a multiuser chat. Also, it will feature a forum, blog, and other similar CRUD applications. The key things I am looking at is

1. Response time
2. Max number of developers may be 1 to 3 during the initial stages
3. I expect the website to scale up to around 1000 concurrent users in a year, and then hopefully an exponential growth.
4. The users are expected to spend a lot of time, in the site.

With this requirements in mind, I looked at Django, and Web2Py, since I am knowledgable in Python. It fits the bill mostly, but, I am concerned about the scalability, and as it scales, I will require more servers to be added. This means, additional cost, and I don't have any ideas to monetize the app in the near future for various reasons. So, I have to be satisfied with a limited amount of resources.

Can you kindly advice me?

Thx
Ik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you had described, Node.js is perfect. Not only does it have a **low memory footprint** and can it **handle thousands of concurrent clients** out of the box, but you can definitely use it for scraping websites (see [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-node-js-and-jquery/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211486/scrape-web-pages-in-real-time-with-node-js)), creating chats (check [nodechat](http://fzysqr.com/2011/02/28/nodechat-js-using-node-js-backbone-js-socket-io-and-redis-to-make-a-real-time-chat-app/) and this other nice [tutorial](http://www.adityaravishankar.com/2011/10/nowjs-node-js-tutorial-creating-multi-room-chat-server/))

1. The respond time depends on your application, but if you code the right way (don't block the event loop of Node.js, keep you 'heavy-lifting' outside the server process) Node.js is really fast.
2. This depends on you, but consider Node.js is JavaScript on the server-side, so there is already a great pool of developers that already know JS and could learn Node.js specific things fast.
3. There were some official benchmarks on the nodejs blog some weeks ago, look here: http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/11/05/node-v0-6-0/ A simple server with Node.js can handle 5-6 thousands of requests per second, so you can imagine that's really something.
4. Spending a lot of time on the site means that they'll be making many requests, so look at my point above 3).

Answer (score 0):

http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/2/22/is-nodejs-becoming-a-part-of-the-stack-simplegeo-says-yes.html

[Scaling node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710420/scaling-node-js)