# Clustering Node JS in Heavy Traffic Production Environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing, node-cluster

I have a web service handling http requests to redirect to specific URLs.  Right the CPU is hammered at about 5 million hits per day, but I need to scale it up to handle 20 million plus.  This is a production environment so I am a little apprehensive about the new Node Cluster method b/c it is still listed as experimental.  I need suggestions on how to cluster Node on handle the traffic on a linux server.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, you already have the Node-based answer -- the [cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). Beyond Node are numerous options for [load balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)#Vendors) multiple physical or virtual machines that each execute your web service. Though, note that any truly breaking changes will appear between major/minor versions -- [v0.6 vs v0.8](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/API-changes-between-v0.6-and-v0.8) -- rather than between revisions -- e.g., [v0.6.15 vs. v0.6.16](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/30/version-0-6-16-stable/).

Comment: I think you mean scaling (also)? =>  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4710617/11926

Answer (score 0):

5 million per day is equivalent to 57.87 per second, and 25 million is 289.4 per second. These numbers are not too much for a single server for your case. If you only want to redirect specif urls, you can go with another alternatives such as [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) that is more fit for that job. However, if you still want to use NodeJS, I think a modern server can handle that load. Look at my blog post as an example of how to use clustering: [NodeJS: Simple Clustering Benchmark](http://mustafaakin.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/nodejs-simple-clustering-benchmark/). If you want to use all of your cores, you should use clustering.

Comment: Without information on the software versions used, the referenced information is totally meaningless. Cluster is limited to Node < v0.6 and so doesn't run on the current version. Native clustering doesn't appear until the next version of Node.