# Sending message to a specific connected users using webSocket?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I wrote a code for broadcasting a message to *all* users:

```
// websocket and http servers
var webSocketServer = require('websocket').server;

...
...
var clients = [ ];

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    // Not important for us. We're writing WebSocket server, not HTTP server
});
server.listen(webSocketsServerPort, function() {
  ...
});

var wsServer = new webSocketServer({
    // WebSocket server is tied to a HTTP server. 
    httpServer: server
});

// This callback function is called every time someone
// tries to connect to the WebSocket server
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
...
var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin); 
var index = clients.push(connection) - 1;
...
```

Please notice:

- I don't have any user reference but only a connection .
- All users connection are stored in an `array`.

**Goal**: Let's say that the Node.js server wants to send a message to a specific client (John). How would the NodeJs server know which connection John has? The Node.js server doesn't even know John. all it sees is the connections.

So, I believe that now, I shouldn't store users only by their connection, instead, I need to store an object, which will contain the `userId` and the `connection` object.

**Idea:**

- When the page finishes loading (DOM ready) - establish a connection to the Node.js server.
- When the Node.js server accept a connection - generate a unique string and send it to the client browser. Store the user connection and the unique string in an object. e.g. `{UserID:"6", value: {connectionObject}}`
- At client side, when this message arrives - store it in a hidden field or cookie. (for future requests to the NodeJs server )

---

When the server wants to send a message to John:

- Find john's UserID in the dictionary and send a message by the corresponding connection.
- please notice there is no asp.net server code invloced here (in the message mechanism). only NodeJs .*

**Question:**

Is this the right way to go?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This is not only the right way to go, but the only way. Basically each connection needs a unique ID. Otherwise you won't be able to identify them, it's as simple as that.

Now how you will represent it it's a different thing. Making an object with `id` and `connection` properties is a good way to do that ( I would definitely go for it ). You could also attach the `id` directly to connection object.

Also remember that if you want communication between users, then you have to send target user's ID as well, i.e. when user A wants to send a message to user B, then obviously A has to know the ID of B.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Again, you don't have much choice. Browser will kill the connection, so you have  tohandle disconnection and reconnection. Also you probably will want to implement some kind of timeout mechanism (destroy the wrapper object on the server side only after timeout) to avoid unnecessary notifications when this happens (assuming you want to notify other users about disconnection).

Comment: @RoyiNamir As for two unique names: the other idea is to keep the object `SOCKETS = {};` on the server side and add a socket to a list for a give ID, i.e. `SOCKETS["John"] = [];` and `SOCKETS["John"].push(conn);`. You will probably need that since a user can open multiple tabs.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I don't know what library you are using, but normally there should be a handler for that. Note that this will only work, when client terminates the connection properly (like closing the tab/browser for example). If something wrong happens (power plant explodes ;)), then you won't now about that. Therefore you will need a pinging mechanism anyway.

Comment: https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node ( and I know I should move to Socket.io) :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yep, I think that will do: `connection.on('close', callback);`. As for Socket.IO: that's totally your opinion. :) I don't like it at all, since it doesn't scale well.

Comment: Really ? Thanks for that info. ( about scaling). I will think about your solution more deeply. thanks :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir No worries, let me know if you have more questions. :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Guys I read your explanations and am following http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket011.htm#BABGCEHE but not sure how to attach users ids to connection object should I attach them at theend of url ? ws://localhost:8080/dukeetf2/dukeetf?id=2123 ?

Comment: @freakish Guys I read your explanations and am following http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket011.htm#BABGCEHE but not sure how to attach users ids to connection object should I attach them at theend of url ? ws://localhost:8080/dukeetf2/dukeetf?id=2123 ?

Comment: @freakish : Careful, this is only a good solution for a one process app. If you scale your application using multiple processes (or servers), they will not share the same memory - so the iteration using locally stored objects will not work. It's better to iterate all the local connections directly, storing the UUID on the connection itself. Also, for scaling I would recommend Redis.

Comment: From my experience I store all user connection id to Redis then use pub feature of Redis to publish send message event to all process then let each process handle it. It work well!!

Comment: Can you please tell me how to send message to a particular client using connection object? I have saved the user id in connection object as stated above. I just want to know how to use connection object while sending message from server to particular client(i have id and connection object of that user). Thanks.

Comment: @Myst, can you please explain how exactly,able to to scale ? Also I store the id in connection object itself , is all the connection object will shared across the multiple servers if am using a load-balancer.?

Comment: @AsishAP , this is a long discussion... I recommend that you start with reading [this article](https://hackernoon.com/scaling-websockets-9a31497af051) just to get oriented and than maybe search SO for other questions, [here's one worth reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710420/scaling-node-js).

Comment: what about this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364243/websocketserver-node-js-how-to-differentiate-clients#comment55441648_17223609 saying that your solution is not thread-safe?

Comment: @T.Todua what do you mean? I don't see anyone mentioning threads in the link. Besides, JavaScript is single threaded, it doesn't have thread safety issues.

Comment: @freakish it's not mentioning the thread or answer per se, I mean, that person commented below another answer, which was like your answer, and says that, storing the  ids in variable is not safe and causes unexpected results. please read my referred comment to understand the problem and mention two words - if you can of course as a courtesy.

Comment: @T.Todua there's absolutely nothing unsafe about storing ids in variable. Plus I'm not sure what an alternative is. I mean, variables store data, that's what they are for. Even if you write scalable, multiserver solution, even if you use Redis or something else, each server still has to keep track of its own connections. There's no way to avoid this.

Answer (score 57):

Here's a simple chat server private/direct messaging.

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "chat-server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "WebSocket chat server",
  "dependencies": {
    "ws": "0.4.x"
  }
}
```

`server.js`

```
var webSocketServer = new (require('ws')).Server({port: (process.env.PORT || 5000)}),
    webSockets = {} // userID: webSocket

// CONNECT /:userID
// wscat -c ws://localhost:5000/1
webSocketServer.on('connection', function (webSocket) {
  var userID = parseInt(webSocket.upgradeReq.url.substr(1), 10)
  webSockets[userID] = webSocket
  console.log('connected: ' + userID + ' in ' + Object.getOwnPropertyNames(webSockets))

  // Forward Message
  //
  // Receive               Example
  // [toUserID, text]      [2, "Hello, World!"]
  //
  // Send                  Example
  // [fromUserID, text]    [1, "Hello, World!"]
  webSocket.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('received from ' + userID + ': ' + message)
    var messageArray = JSON.parse(message)
    var toUserWebSocket = webSockets[messageArray[0]]
    if (toUserWebSocket) {
      console.log('sent to ' + messageArray[0] + ': ' + JSON.stringify(messageArray))
      messageArray[0] = userID
      toUserWebSocket.send(JSON.stringify(messageArray))
    }
  })

  webSocket.on('close', function () {
    delete webSockets[userID]
    console.log('deleted: ' + userID)
  })
})
```

#### Instructions

To test it out, run `npm install` to install [`ws`](https://github.com/einaros/ws). Then, to start the chat server, run `node server.js` (or `npm start`) in one Terminal tab. Then, in another Terminal tab, run `wscat -c ws://localhost:5000/1`, where `1` is the connecting user's user ID. Then, in a third Terminal tab, run `wscat -c ws://localhost:5000/2`, and then, to send a message from user `2` to `1`, enter `["1", "Hello, World!"]`.

#### Shortcomings

This chat server is very simple.

- Persistence

  It doesn't store messages to a database, such as PostgreSQL. So, the user you're sending a message to must be connected to the server to receive it. Otherwise, the message is lost.
- Security

  It is insecure.

  - If I know the server's URL and Alice's user ID, then I can impersonate Alice, ie, connect to the server as her, allowing me to receive her new incoming messages and send messages from her to any user whose user ID I also know. To make it more secure, modify the server to accept your access token (instead of your user ID) when connecting. Then, the server can get your user ID from your access token and authenticate you.
  - I'm not sure if it supports a WebSocket Secure (`wss://`) connection since I've only tested it on `localhost`, and I'm not sure how to connect securely from `localhost`.

Comment: Does anyone know how to make a [WebSocket Secure localhost connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469445/websocket-secure-localhost-connection)?

Comment: Same here. But if you replace the 'upgradeReq...' part with 'ws.upgradeReq.headers['sec-websocket-key']' it works. (via https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/310 )

Comment: Best example to kick start the WS in practice ! Thanks

Comment: Great example! I've been looking for an answer like this for the past few days

Comment: How to send messages outside ws.on("connection") ??

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot just send back a websocket response to one client. You have to send it back to anyone who has a connection open to a specific WS URL. You can use IDs to choose who you want to display the data to, inside the client GUI?

Answer (score 16):

For people using `ws` version 3 or above. If you want to use the answer provided by [@ma11hew28](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242933/ma11hew28), simply change this block as following.

```js
webSocketServer.on('connection', function (webSocket) {
  var userID = parseInt(webSocket.upgradeReq.url.substr(1), 10)
```

```js
webSocketServer.on('connection', function (webSocket, req) {
  var userID = parseInt(req.url.substr(1), 10)
```

`ws` package has moved `upgradeReq` to request object and you can check the following link for further detail.

Reference: https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1114

Comment: you saved me from a whole lot of hassle.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share what I have done. Hope it doesn't waste your time.

I created database table holding field ID, IP, username, logintime and logouttime. When a user logs in logintime will be currect unixtimestamp unix. And when connection is started in websocket database checks for largest logintime. It will be come user logged in.

And for when user logs out it will store currect logouttime. The user will become who left the app.

Whenever there is new message, Websocket ID and IP are compared and related username will be displayed. Following are sample code...

```
// when a client connects
function wsOnOpen($clientID) {
      global $Server;
      $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

      require_once('config.php');
      require_once CLASSES . 'class.db.php';
      require_once CLASSES . 'class.log.php';

      $db = new database();
      $loga = new log($db);

      //Getting the last login person time and username
      $conditions = "WHERE which = 'login' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1";
      $logs = $loga->get_logs($conditions);
      foreach($logs as $rows) {

              $destination = $rows["user"];
              $idh = md5("$rows[user]".md5($rows["time"]));

              if ( $clientID > $rows["what"]) {
                      $conditions = "ip = '$ip', clientID = '$clientID'  

                      WHERE logintime = '$rows[time]'";
                      $loga->update_log($conditions);
             }
      }
      ...//rest of the things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

interesting post (similar to what I am doing). 
We are making an API (in C#) to connect dispensers with WebSockets, for each dispenser we create a ConcurrentDictionary that stores the WebSocket and the DispenserId making it easy for each Dispenser to create a WebSocket and use it afterwards without thread problems (invoking specific functions on the WebSocket like GetSettings or RequestTicket).
The difference for you example is the use of ConcurrentDictionary instead of an array to isolate each element (never attempted to do such in javascript).
Best regards,

Comment: This can be a comment and not an answer. PLease, read the rules.