# WebSocket Secure localhost connection

Tags: node.js, security, ssl, websocket, localhost

I've built a simple [Node.js WebSocket chat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280747/sending-message-to-a-specific-connected-users-using-websocket/19469286#19469286).

I can run it on `localhost` in a terminal tab.

In another terminal tab, I can connect to it with `wscat`, using `ws://`.

How do I connect to it on `localhost` with `wss://`?

Comment: Don't you do the same thing?

Comment: No, `wscat` doesn't connect with `Error: socket hang up`.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [this example code](https://github.com/einaros/ws/blob/master/examples/ssl.js) for how to establish an HTTPS server which will handle the TCP and TLS layers and then the `ws` module can handle the websocket aspects integrating with that server. You'll need a TLS certificate. For development you can generate your own and sign it yourself. A web search for "self-signed certificate" should lead you to the info you need for that part.