# SocketRocket crashes Node.js WebSocket

Tags: ios, node.js, crash, websocket, socketrocket

I wrote a simple [Node.js WebSocket chat server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19469286/242933). To run the server, I'm using `foreman start` with a `Procfile` that merely contains the line: `chat: npm start`.

I also wrote an iPhone app that uses [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) to connect to the aforementioned server. In `applicationDidEnterBackground:`, I call `close` on `webSocket`. And, In `applicationWillEnterForeground:`, I recreate `webSocket` and call `open`.

When entering the background or foreground, the iPhone app seems to crash the server with the error:

```
chat.1 | events.js:74
chat.1 |         throw TypeError('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.');
chat.1 |               ^
chat.1 | TypeError: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
chat.1 |     at TypeError (<anonymous>)
chat.1 |     at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:74:15)
chat.1 |     at Receiver.self._receiver.onerror (~/Projects/Chat/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:719:10)
chat.1 |     at Receiver.error (~/Projects/Chat/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:301:8)
chat.1 |     at Receiver.opcodes.8.finish (~/Projects/Chat/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:497:14)
chat.1 |     at Receiver.<anonymous> (~/Projects/Chat/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:478:33)
chat.1 |     at Receiver.add (~/Projects/Chat/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:93:24)
chat.1 |     at Socket.firstHandler (~/Projects/Chat/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:678:22)
chat.1 |     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
chat.1 |     at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
chat.1 | npm ERR! weird error 8
chat.1 | npm ERR! not ok code 0
chat.1 | exited with code 1
system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Why is this happening? And, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered same error yesterday, and was able to fix it on Node.Js side by attaching 'error' event handler

```
wss.on('connection', function(connection) {
  connection.on('error', function(reason, code) {
    console.log('socket error: reason ' + reason + ', code ' + code);
  });
}
```

I will try to find what's causing that in SocketRocket code, but for now it works with

Comment: did you figure this out?