# Heroku Node.js WebSocket Server

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket

The Heroku Dev Center article [Using WebSockets on Heroku with Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets) explains how to deploy the [Node.js Websocket Test demo application](https://github.com/heroku-examples/node-ws-test), which uses Express.

However, I'm deploying a [Node.js WebSocket chat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280747/sending-message-to-a-specific-connected-users-using-websocket/19469286#19469286) that doesn't use Express.

When I try to connect from Terminal with `wscat -c ws://my-app.herokuapp.com/1`, I get `error: Error: unexpected server response (503)`. And, `heroku logs` returns `code=H14 desc="No web processes running"`.

Why? How do I fix this?

Note: My `Procfile` is correct: `web: node server.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: **Delete & recreate the app**.

I changed the first line of the [Node.js WebSocket chat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280747/sending-message-to-a-specific-connected-users-using-websocket/19469286#19469286) to:

```
var webSocketServer = new (require('ws')).Server({
      server: require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
        response.end()
      }).listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)
    }),
```

Still didn't work.

Then, I deleted & recreated the Heroku app and deployed. Worked.

Then, I changed the first line back to:

```
var webSocketServer = new (require('ws')).Server({port: (process.env.PORT || 5000)}),
```

and redeployed. Still works!

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect with `curl -vD` to get verbose information on what headers you server is sending?