# Amazon Node.js WebSocket Server Setup

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, system-administration

Does anybody know how to create and configure AWS so that I can deploy a simple Node.js WebSocket server on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Amazon AWS Node.js WebSocket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424380/amazon-aws-node-js-websocket)

Comment: Wow, I forgot I asked this already. Doesn't anyone know how to do this? Bounty time! :-)