# How to scale Node.js application

Tags: node.js

Imagine a large node.js app with a multi-purpose api for mobile and frontend with a serving static files, with a websocket server, lot of cron jobs and workers. Basically I can horizontally or vertically scale a whole app, use a load balancer and so on.

But from a perspective of a business logic, whole app is one big "bundle" where some parts are used more than others, also some parts have bigger impact on a performance of app than another. For example, mobile API may be used 100x more than some cron which starts 1 time per hour to make some cleanup. So is it necessary to scale whole app?

Isn't it better to scale app to separate modules and scale only needed? For example

- mobile api
- FE api
- crons and workers
- websocket
- whatever...

If so, what is proper way to handle business logic? There is a parts of code I would need in every submodule of application, for example database models, migrations (seeders?), maybe I would need some general functionality, like some specific utils functions or enum definitions. So I can create git submodules for them, but there is risk it will be too much complex to handle 4-6 git repositories with a 2-4 git submodules and handle whole app in multiple environments (dev, stage, uat, prod). Are there some others caveats of this approach? Or is it unusable?

I dived into waters of internet and searched for some resources for example [node.js best practice](https://medium.com/@me_37286/yoni-goldberg-javascript-nodejs-testing-best-practices-2b98924c9347), [scaling node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710420/scaling-node-js), [scaling node.js](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/scaling-node-js-applications-8492bd8afadc/), [good scaling practice](https://medium.com/iquii/good-practices-for-high-performance-and-scalable-node-js-applications-part-1-3-bb06b6204197) but it not fully answered all my questions.

Comment: This is an interesting question, alas, not a good fit for Stack Overflow, I'm afraid. It is too broad and opinion based

Comment: Any suggestion to change platform?

Comment: Sorry, wrong comment

Comment: You may want to try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com