# node.js - facebook connect - most updated lib

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I've started playing a bit with node.js. I come from a more php / java background.

i'm heavily using facebook sdk for php, which is very good (for php). node.js lack such support (the JS SDK for facebook is something totaly different correct me if i'm wrong). 
Again, talking about support and using everyauth didn't come up well.. (maybe an updated sample code will help me). For example, how do you paginate via the SDK? (you get a next link from facebook as response)

faceplate - isn't updated (tried it's samples and saw from the code)
there are libs that use FQL and not open graph

which is the "best" ? or most updated "wrapper" or SDK of it's own and yet simple to use? (no need for heavy duty lib)

thank you!

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484825/what-is-the-best-facebook-connect-library-for-node-js/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after searching, waiting for an answer that didn't came, etc.. the end the answer came from node's IRC channel.
http://passportjs.org/guide/index.html

http://passportjs.org/guide/facebook.html